# Java : Interface with 2 method with the same erasure but 2 different wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I have some codes with lot of converter having 2 "apply" method to convert :

- from DTO to Entity
- from Entity to DTO

I need to use them on a new generic service so I want to create an interface to inherit so I write this code :

```
public interface Converter<T,V> {
    public T apply(V input);
    public V apply(T input);
}
```

but now I got an error saying :

> apply(T) and apply(V) have the same erasure

the question :

is there a way to do what i want without having to rewrite all the child classes ?

Answer (score 0):

No.

You have to give them different names.